# Detecting whether innerHtml is readonly

Tags: javascript

I understand that some HTML tags have a readonly innerHtml property in some browsers, e.g. in Internet Explorer,

"The innerHTML property is read-only on the col, colGroup, frameSet, html, head, style, table, tBody, tFoot, tHead, title, and tr objects."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533897(VS.85).aspx

The question is, how do you detect whether this is the case without resorting to a generic browser detect? Simply checking for the property a la

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/support.html

won't differentiate between writable and read-only properties

Comment: Create an element, try to write and look for an exception?

Comment: try `try {
        document.head.innerHTML = "lol";
        alert('winner');
    }catch(e){
        alert('failure');
    }`

Comment: Yes that would work I guess, thanks

Comment: Hmm, actually `document.createElement('tr').innerHTML = 'asf'` doesn't throw on IE 9

Comment: Andy, if that works, it will delete the code in the head.not so good..

Comment: @vsync It's a very stripped down example, depending on what OP wants to do he could edit it of course

Comment: I would still just check IE version (super simple) then make a "blacklisted" array of readOnly elements

Comment: @vsync yes but ideally I'd like to make it future proof, e.g. not have my code be obsolete if IE does at some point support writing

Comment: @Kos, what happens on IE9, does it just silently fail?

Comment: but it's such small code why does it matter if it's there or not. it's couple of bytes of checking IE version.

Comment: @OliverKohll It succeeds (and the `tr`'s innerHTML is visible if you add it to the DOM). But it fails for `head`.

Comment: @Kos OK, looks like I'll try the try/catch method, the particular tag I'm interested in is tbody so I'm not worried about head. Ta

Comment: and how is that better than broswer detection is beyond me. It's not like IE updates itself. if there is a bug, it's there for life, so you might as well just do the smallest test possible.

Comment: @OliverKohll, `tbody` works just like `tr`

Comment: strangely enough, this works: `document.createElement('tr').innerHTML = '1';` but on a "real element, it doesn't.

Comment: Well to browser detect or not to is a well-trodden argument e.g. jQuery and Microsoft both recommend against it on principle. However in this case there seems to be no easy way to feature-detect. The one way that works is to put HTML in the page e.g.

http://jsfiddle.net/okohll/tDA8y/1/

but when you do it in pure JS that doesn't work

Comment: well, Microsoft and jQuery are not the presidents of the universe, and quite frankly I have a brain of my own, and I decide WHEN it's a good idea and when it's not. They only recommend it for beginner developers, who don't have the skills to understand when one is better than the other.